# get the biggest numbre from array key php

Tags: php, arrays

i have these array and what i need to do is to get the separate each array check the [total] and then get the bigest 5 numbers. ive been trying but my head is about to explode, please help!!

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 50 [faceid] => 1508653983 [fname] => Mario [lname] => Zelaya [email] => Email [handicap] => Handicap [province] => Province [country] => Country [gender] => male [hand] => [shot1] => Shot #1 [shot2] => Shot #2 [shot3] => Shot #3 [shot4] => Shot #4 [shot5] => Shot #5 [news] => 1 [total] => 0 )

[1] => Array ( [id] => 49 [faceid] => 1665349411 [fname] => Yair [lname] => Villar [email] => servidorv@gmail.com [handicap] => lefthanded [province] => Buenos Aires [country] => Argentina [gender] => male [hand] => RH [shot1] => 200 [shot2] => 98 [shot3] => 98 [shot4] => 98 [shot5] => 98 [news] => 1 [total] => 592 ) 

[2] => Array ( [id] => 48 [faceid] => 1665349411 [fname] => Yair [lname] => Villar [email] => servidorv@gmail.com [handicap] => lefthanded [province] => Buenos Aires [country] => Argentina [gender] => male [hand] => RH [shot1] => 500 [shot2] => 250 [shot3] => 80 [shot4] => 30 [shot5] => 20 [news] => 1 [total] => 88000 )

)
```

how can i do these with php. please help!!

Comment: Hey don't let people tell you lefthanded is a handicap!

Comment: well im trying to build a function to unset everythin i dont need and only leave [total] and [userid] then try to compare [total] and sort the array desc, then only print the last 5 ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getTop5(array $data, $high2low = true)
{
    $total = array();

    foreach ($data as $val)
        $total[$val["id"]] = $val["total"];

    asort($total);
    return $high2low ? array_reverse($total) : $total;
}

$data = array(
        array("id" => 1, "total" => 25),
        array("id" => 2, "total" => 32),
        array("id" => 3, "total" => 21),
        array("id" => 4, "total" => 28)
        );

print_r(getTop5($data));
```

Comment: perfect bro , so many thanks you :) you made my day lol, now the thing is it returns only the total no the id :( lol but ill figure it out :) thanks man really good help

Comment: @YairVillar your welcome ;) ... You can use array_keys() to get keys of this array and you know that the keys are the ids...

Answer (score 2):

Try using php's usort function to sort your array:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['total'] == $b['total'])
        return 0;

    return ($a['total'] > $b['total']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($yourarray, "cmp");

if (count($yourarray) > 5)
    $sortedArray = array_slice($yourarray, 0, 5);
else
    $sortedArray = $yourarray;
```

You will end up with an array with the 5 elements with the highest score. If there are less than 5 elements in your input array, you end up with as many elements as there are in your input array.

Comment: You could shorten your `cmp()` to `return $b['total'] - $a['total']`.

Comment: Agreed, but for the sake of clarity, the expanded version of cmp is a bit easier to understand :)